# How to create custom taxonomy field searchable?

Tags: wordpress, tags, custom-taxonomy

I have added custom taxonomy field on tags, but when I search that field search is not working. Any way to make it searchable in WordPress dashboard?

Comment: can you please add your custom taxonomy code here.

Comment: have you created you custom taxonomy searchable. like  'exclude_from_search' => false

Comment: also add code of your custom taxonomy.

Comment: In custom taxonomy I have four fields out of them 3 are default which are name, slug and description which are searchable but I have added one custom field which is not searchable.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16637/how-to-filter-post-listing-in-wp-dashboard-posts-listing-using-a-custom-field/16641#16641

see this link. i hope this helps you better

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the code. You can change $post_type and $custom_fields according to your needs.

```
   function extend_admin_search( $query ) {

// Extend search for document post type
$post_type = 'document';
// Custom fields to search for
/* $custom_fields = array(
"_file_name",
); */

if( ! is_admin() )
return;

if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
return;

$search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

// Set to empty, otherwise it won't find anything
$query->query_vars['s'] = '';

/* if ( $search_term != '' ) {
$meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
array_push( $meta_query, array(
'key' => $custom_field,
'value' => $search_term,
'compare' => 'LIKE'
));
}

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}; */
$query->set( 's', $search_term );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search' );
```

Comment: I have tried but not working. $query->query_vars['s'] this field is empty and got different post type,  url is "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&post_type=post&s=wed"

Comment: I am not searching on posts . I am searching on tags and I am not getting search keyword in query vars. Search keyword show empty.